# Azure move app service to a different app service plan

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-app-service-plans

I have the following setup:

- Resource group 1

  - App service plan 1
  - App Service 1 (app service plan 1)
- Resource group 2

  - App service plan 2
  - App Service 2 (app service plan 2)
  - App Service 3 (app service plan 1)

I would like to move `App Service 3` which is into `Resource group 2` but uses `app service plan 1`, to `app service plan 2`.

Is this possible? I have tried to use the feature "Change App service plan" available on the new portal but when I click on it a blade appear saying that "No App Service plan found".

I suspect that the blade looks for app service plan available on the original resource group and does not permit neither to create a new one.

Please see the attached picture for details.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Current and new App Service plans should be in the same geo-region - do they in your case?

Comment: @Lanorkin: Yes, all the resources are in same geo-region.

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread?

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT: Sorry, I have been taken by other commitments. It is ok. I am going to close the post and assign the bounty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I would like to move App Service 3 which is into Resource group 2 but uses app service plan 1, to app service plan 2. Is this possible?

Based on my understanding App Service Plan 1 in the **resource group 1** and Service Plan 2 in the **resource group 2**, we can't do that from azure portal currently. According to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview#move-an-app-to-a-different-app-service-plan), we could change service that in the same resource group and geographical location.

> Only valid plans (in the same resource group and geographical location) are shown

About we could not create App service plan in the change service plan interface, and I also repro it. In my option,it is not a development issue, and we could report a ticket in the azure portal.

[image]

But we also could create a new App service plan in the **same resource group (Resource Group 1) and geographical**, then try to change the service plan, it will be shown in the change Service Plan interface.

In my option, it is not recommended that WebApp application and Service Plan are not in the same resource group.

Comment: [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#app-service-limitations) state 
_App Service plan do not need to reside in the same resource group as the app for the app to function correctly._

Comment: You can currently move to another plan if THREE conditions are met: The new plan must (1) exist in the same resource group, (2) exist in the same geographical region, and (3) exist in the same webspace ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage)). The first two conditions are straightforward, the third is hard to determine and impossible to change. [Cloning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning) is currently the only option if you still can't move to the plan you want to.

Comment: Cloning is not available on Linux Apps, not available for Function Apps ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning#current-restrictions)). Looks like the only way to move, say, an Azure Function w/ Python runtime to a different App Service Plan outside the current Resource Group is to completely recreate it...

Answer (score 1):

Are App service plan 1 and App service plan 2 in the same region?

You can have resources in multiple regions in the same resource group, but App Services and App Service plan must be in the same region.

My best guess is:

- App service plan 1, App Service 1, and App Service 3 are in Region X.
- App service plan 2 and App Service 2 are in Region Y.

You might have to recreate App Service 1a in App Service Plan 2. :(

Comment: What does that do to the Function App URL? Will it remain after recreation?