# App Service Plan not found when trying to change Azure App Service's plan

Tags: azure

I am trying to change the Azure App Service Plan for one of my Azure App Services and below is what I get. It is not able to search the App Service Plan that I just created.

[image: No App Services found]

Both the current App Service Plan of my Azure App Service and the one that I want to change to exist in the same location and same resource group. Only difference in both the plans is pricing tier. The existing plan happens to be in "Standard: 2 Small" and the one that I just created is in "Standard: 1 Small". For both the plans I chose the pricing tier to be "Standard 1" so not sure how this is adding the number 1 and 2 in pricing tier name.

Also please note that this question is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636279/azure-move-app-service-to-a-different-app-service-plan).

Comment: I guess this is due to some Azure cache. Did you try to log out and log in again? I have experienced this, but usually after some time it has been resolved.

Comment: Make sure the plan is correspond to the correct os of app service, i.e, if your app service os is windows(linux), the plan should be windows(linux).

Comment: @JoyWang, the OS is defined per App Service, not per App Service Plan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

a) this is due to some cache not being refreshed. Either wait and/or try to log out and log in again.

b) If you have moved one of the plans between resource groups so that both are in the same RG, then this is not supposed to work. It is due to the way service plans are created. Initially, they are put into a specific isolated webspace, called "App Service Environment". This is a combination of Location and RG, and cannot be changed even if the Plan is later moved to another RG. Read [Move an app to another App Service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage#move-an-app-to-another-app-service-plan) for more details.

Comment: My App Service is in a different RG than the current App service plan. I was creating new app service plan in RG as my app service and that wasn't working. Now when I created in RG as current app service plan, it worked. Also. not quite sure if this is how it works because I tried logging out and back in.